# How to reset or restart root view of UIViewController to its original state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS Development. I have a very simple UIViewController, with two button in the view. I am allowing users to edit UI components or drag and drop from one place to another. Now I want to implement reset functionality allowing users to reset UI to its original stage discarding all the changes.

As mentioned in several post tried setNeedsDisplay but looks like its not right way to achieve this. What are the my options ?

e.g. **In Android world, you can finish current Activity (Equivalent of UIViewController) and relaunch self to achieve original state.** Is it possible to do something like it in iOS.

```
- (IBAction)resetButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    // Now I want discard all the changes on the screen 
    // On some button click or specific action from user.

    // Tried calling setNeedsDisplay as pointed in few others answers but somehow 
    // setNeedsDisplay does not reload my ViewController.
    // [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
  }
```

Comment: why you set android tag?

Comment: u still have problem with that ? u do not accept any answer ? let us  know what happened with u ?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar.  What I did was:

1) create local CGRect variables for each frame ui control i.e. CGRect originalFrame1;

2) get the original frame position for each ui control and store them on viewDidLoad i.e. originalFrame1 = _frame1.frame;

3) on the resetButtonClicked set it back to is original position _frame1.frame = originalFrame1;

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1- Save the positions of your initial state, and when the user clicks the reset button, just put those buttons on their initial states.

2- OR (strange way of doing it), you can initialise the same controller you are in and just present it from itself, that should be somehow close to your android approach. You'll get the same controller on its initial state (If you didn't didn't dismiss the first one, you should)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks option 1 will definitely help with positions but it will fail if view background changed or some Text edited. hence considering option 2

Answer (score 0):

u can save the positions for all subviews(buttons,label,...) in the main view.

`self.view.subview` it will return array contain all elements u have it :)

and when u wanna rest your view just get the old position for each subview from the array.

```
NSArray *arrayOfView = [view subviews]; 
//also:
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOfView = [[view subviews] mutableCopy];

for (UIImageView *imageView in imageViewArray) //uiimageview or whatever your subview //is you can check by using isKindofClass. `if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])` 
{
    //let's set frame for image view before adding to
    [myimageView setFrame:imageview.frame];//or something like that 

}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, it will definitely set view to its original position but what if text or some thing else changes. To be more precise, Want to implement discard like functionality.

Answer (score 0):

EVery app will have a **keyWindow** object for which you should assign some viewController to display.

**window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];**

Lets say your controller's class is **CustomViewController**

So, in your app delegate,**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, you will write

**self.window.rootViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];**

And the function invoked when you click **reset** button be as below,

```
-(void)reset{
   // reset the view with default
   self.view.window.rootViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];

}
```

If you follow above code, it won't have any memory leaks because ,when you set rootViewController again ,the old one will be lost and removed from memory.

Comment: Thanks, it works for view which are not loaded from the nib. I tried doing same but it gives me following exception  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.

Comment: I tried with viewController linked with nib and having outlets.It perfectly worked fine to me. there might be some other outlet issue with your code.Put break points and debug it.

Comment: Do you have some code example, I can refer. I tried it now not getting any error but now it just show blank window.